# Android server-initiated TCP connection

Tags: android, tcp, connection

I am new to Android development and I would like to know if there is any way to establish a server-initiated tcp connection on an Android device.

What I'm trying to achieve is making an external server able to access data from the Android phone at any time without using a battery-draining permanent connection.

As it is not possible for the phone to do something similar to an `accept()` when it is on 3G, I was wondering if there might be a system of "hidden" notifications that could be used to tell the phone to connect to the server.

Another option would be for the phone to try a connection every X seconds but I don't like the idea, and I'd rather have the connection to be created as soon as it's needed.

Are there any 'clean' solutions to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html).